# bash: assign punctuation to variable

Tags: bash, unix

when I assign like this:

```
rmall="\,\.\?\!\:\;\(\)\[\]\{\}\"\'"
```

then echo $rmall, I got this:

```
\,\.\?\!\:\;\(\)\[\]\{\}\"\'
```

But what I want is only , How can I do?

```
,.?!:;()[]{}"'
```

as later I need to remove those.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are double quoting by using quotes *and* backslashes. Use one or the other.

Note: You will always need to use backslash for escaping your quote character but otherwise not needed.

Comment: In other words, either `rmall=\,\.\?\!\:\;\(\)\[\]\{\}\"\'` or `rmall=",.?!:;()[]{}\"'"` but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Inside double quotes, only three escape sequences are treated specially:

1. `\"` is replaced by a literal `"`
2. `\$` is replaced by a literal `$`
3. `\\` is replaced by a literal `\`

These three are required to allow the literal character in contexts where they would normally produce special behavior. `\"`, obviously, lets you include a double-quote inside a double-quoted string. `\$` lets you output a literal dollar sign where it would otherwise trigger parameter substitution:

```
bash $ foo=5; echo "\$foo = $foo"
$foo = 5
```

`\\` lets you output a literal backslash that precedes a parameter substitution or at the end of a string.

```
bash $ foo=5; echo "\\$foo"
\5
bash $ echo "Use a \\"
Use a \
```

A backslash followed by any other character is treated literally:

```
bash $ echo "\x"
\x
```